# How can I check Linux CPU usage from bash?

Tags: linux, bash

My apologies if this is a double/triple post. I've found multiple answers and the all return slightly different results. I'm very unsure which one would be the 'correct' one to follow or if any of them are not actually providing me a correct value.

I have a Linux machine that i am unable to install further applications on and i'm trying to run a bash script that will show the total CPU usage at regular intervals. Below is one that i found online which seems to give me what I'm after but i'm not 100% confident that this is going to pull the correct CPU usage information due to it pulling the data from TOP which from what I believe, will not pull a true value due to it pulling an average from when the UNIX machine was booted?

Thanks in advance

```
echo print `top -n 1 | tr -s " " | cut -d$" " -f10 | tail -n +8 | head -n -1 | paste -sd+ | bc`/ `nproc` | python
```

Comment: A long pipeline like that will, if run frequently enough (or on a low-powered/embedded system), potentially increase the average on its own! On Linux, do the easy thing and just read the numbers directly from `/proc`.

Comment: Any time you use backticks or pipes in shell, that forks a new copy of the shell to run that component of the pipeline; every time you use a command like top or tr or cut in that pipeline that isn't built into the shell itself, similarly, it's another program that gets started, run, and cleaned up after; none of these things are free.

Comment: ...and no, top does not pull an average from boot.

Comment: It turns out i had not informed myself as much as i thought i had! I will look further into this :) thanks @CharlesDuffy for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much more efficient is to directly read `/proc/loadavg`, thus collecting the data directly from the kernel.

```
IFS=$' \t/' read -r load_1min load_5min load_15min load_inst_cur load_inst_tot _ </proc/loadavg
echo "Average load over the last minute: $load_1min"
echo "Number of runnable processes this instant: $load_inst_cur of $load_inst_tot"
```

Note that load average is is not strictly CPU usage -- it also measures processes waiting for I/O resources.